# insert image in layout dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have to insert image in layout dynamically.when width or height of image is bigger than layout,image go out of boundary of layout.
I don't want show out of layout image.please help me.
my code:

```
   ComputeCarpetSize computeCarpetSize = new ComputeCarpetSize();
        float[] size = computeCarpetSize.newSize(workSpaceWidth, workSpaceHeight, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
        int divScalex=ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceWidth * image.getScaleX()))/ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[0]));
        int  divScaley=ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceHeight * image.getScaleY()))/ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[1]));


        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
        if (params != null) {
            if (sizeWidth > ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceWidth)) {
                params.width = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[0]));
                imageView.setScaleX(divScalex);

            } else {
                params.width = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceWidth * image.getScaleX()));
            }
            if (sizeHeight > ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceHeight)) {
                params.height = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[1]));
                imageView.setScaleY(divScaley);

            } else {
                params.height = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceHeight * image.getScaleY()));
            }
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

        } else {
            params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (sizeWidth > ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceWidth)) {
                params.width = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[0]));
                imageView.setScaleX(divScalex);

            } else {
                params.width = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceWidth * image.getScaleX()));
            }
            if (sizeHeight > ViewUtil.dpToPx(workSpaceHeight)) {
                params.height = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(size[1]));
                imageView.setScaleY(divScaley);


            } else {
                params.height = ViewUtil.dpToPx((int) Math.round(workSpaceHeight * image.getScaleY()));
            }
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

Comment: what do you want those math for? just add `ImageView` to the parent layout and your image will be scaled automatically

Comment: because I have to load save design in application and web. so math should exactly same to other loaded design.